# How to mock Restriction.eq( ) using Mockito

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I´m having some trouble to create tests with Mockito. During debug with Eclipse i got a `null` from `Restrictions.eq`, i did every step to create a static mock to `Restrictions`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ RequisicaoList.class, StatusMessages.class,
    FacesMessages.class, Restrictions.class })
public class RequisicaoListTest {

...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String criteriaContigencia() {
    Criteria criteria = criarCriteria(Requisicao.class);

    criteria.createAlias("produto", "prod");        
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("prod.ar",arSelecionada));

    if (getExemplo().getNrProtocolo() != null)
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nrProtocolo", getExemplo()
                .getNrProtocolo()));

    situacoesPesquisa.clear();
    situacoesPesquisa.add(SituacaoRequisicao.PENDENTE_PAGAMENTO);
    situacoesPesquisa.add(SituacaoRequisicao.PENDENTE_AGENDAMENTO);
    if (!situacoesPesquisa.isEmpty()) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("situacao", situacoesPesquisa));
    }   

    if (getExemplo().getResponsavel() != null && StringUtils.isNotBlank(getExemplo().getResponsavel().getCpf())) {
            criteria = criteria.createCriteria("responsavel");
            criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cpf", getExemplo().getResponsavel().getCpf()));
    }

    resultado = Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(),Requisicao.class);

    return null;
}
```

My code is mixing managedBean with persistence layer, i can´t change that, but i must create tests to that project.

The problem here is to mock

```
Restrictions.eq("cpf", getExemplo().getResponsavel().getCpf())
```

because even i do:

```
SimpleExpression simpleExpressionEq = mock(SimpleExpression.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Restrictions.class);
when(Restrictions.eq("cpf", "00000000091")).thenReturn(simpleExpressionEq);
```

then I still getting `null` return from `Restriction.eq`, even passing the specting values. But during debug, if i make a expression in the Expression View doing:

```
Restrictions.eq("cpf", "00000000091"))
```

It works fine and returns a mocked `SimpleExpression`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to mock `Restrictions` when you test this method.  The purpose of this method is to wrap the data access (Hibernate and whatever database you're using).  So, a useful test for this method would be a test that ensures that you're using the database correctly.

So, instead of writing a unit test where everything is mocked, I would recommend writing an integration test.  Use an in-memory database such as H2 (http://h2database.com); and write a test that sets up appropriate data, then actually selects it.  Then, your level of confidence that this method is actually doing what it ought to do will far exceed what a unit test would give you.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
Restrictions.eq("cpf", "00000000091"))
```

is returning correctly, then perhaps the problem is with `getExemplo().getResponsavel().getCpf()`.  Are you sure it's returning "00000000091"? You haven't included enough code to tell if that could be the issue, but it's worth investigating.

Another approach would be to avoid mocking `Restrictions` altogether.  When I want to do something like this, I use the real Restrictions class and let it return a real Criterion.  I wrote a simple "toStringEq" matcher that I can use to mock or verify the behavior of the Criteria object.  Of course, matching on the toString() value of objects is not the same as matching for actual equality, but since Criterion objects use instance equality for equality, but to Criterion objects that have the same toString() value are functionally equivalent, I've found it to be pretty convenient for this use case.

For example, after your call, provided you have a mock Criteria object, you could have:

```
verify(mockCriteria).add(argThat(toStringEq(Restrictions.eq("cpf", "0000000091"))));
```

Here is the simple matcher class:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

public class HamcrestToStringMatcher<T> extends ArgumentMatcher<T> {

    private T toMatch;

    public HamcrestToStringMatcher(T toMatch) {
        this.toMatch = toMatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(toMatch == null ? "null" : toMatch.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
        return ((toMatch == null && argument == null) || (toMatch != null
                && argument != null && toMatch.toString().equals(
                argument.toString())));
    }

    public static <T> HamcrestToStringMatcher<T> toStringEq(T toMatch) {
        return new HamcrestToStringMatcher<T>(toMatch);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, it was my fault, i had a complain for some dependencies, so i was changing the code but was unable to compile and running an old code.